# What's the meaning of "I shouldn't mind a little something"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Christopher Robin asked pooh, "What do you like doing best in the world, Pooh?"

> he said, "What I like best in the whole world is Me and Piglet going to see You, and You saying 'What about a little something?' and Me saying,' Well, **I shouldn't mind a little something**, should you, Piglet,' and it being a hummy sort of day outside, and birds singing."

This is from "The House At Pooh Corner". I think that "a little something" is "a little something to eat". Does this phrase "I shouldn't mind a little thing" mean "Pooh don't have to need a little something"? But as you know , Pooh likes to eat.
Or does "I shouldn't mind a little something" mean "I shouldn't mind eating a little something"? That means "Pooh wants to eat it".

Comment: "And it is that word ‘hummy,’ my darlings, that makes the first place in The House at Pooh Corner at which Tonstant Weader Fwowed up" --Dorothy Parker as *Constant Reader* in the New Yorker. 1928

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - hummy or hunny?

Comment: "Hummy".  A pants-less anthropomorphic bear can't be expected to have perfect pronunciation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

'I wouldn't mind...' and (slightly old-fashioned, 1928, remember?) 'I shouldn't mind...' both mean 'I would not refuse or object to...'. It's British/English understatement and means 'I would be happy to have (or do)...'. And, yes, in this context, 'a little something' means 'something to eat'.

Comment: A somewhat less old-fashioned (or at least still in common use today) equivalent might be "**Don't mind if I do**".

Comment: Perhaps for further explanation, to "mind" something here means to dislike it or object to it, so "I wouldn't mind it" means "I woundn't dislike it", that is, I would like it.

Answer (score 1):

In the same vein as Michael Harvey, but my grandmother's idea of a "little something" would have been an alcoholic drink.

Comment: That's clearly not the correct answer in this context, though.